# Conditional formatting formula for exact match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm sorry if this has been answered in any form.. I was unable to find anything that I could apply to help my situation since my list is so long.

I have large spreadsheets (1000-3000 lines) and i'm using the following formula in conditional formatting to highlight my spreadsheet rows.

Example formula:

`=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("Accounting",$C1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Retl Wor",$C1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Finance",$C1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("FINANCE - ARC",$C1)),ISNUMBER(FIND("Audit",$C1)))`

This formula is shortened (I have about 40-60 words in them. I have 3 formulas; One to highlight yellow, one to highlight green, one to highlight red). This formula is working decently but it also highlights cells containing the word "Accounting". So the word "Chem Accounting" is being highlighted, as well. I don't want this to happen.. I need my formula to highlight only EXACT matches.
Thank you for any advice/help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Then use `EXACT()`: `OR(EXACT($C1,"Accounting"),...`

Comment: Oh man..I tried this but it didn't work before.. I must've done something incorrectly..That was too simple. Should i leave this post up? @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of exact matches and FINDs where needed.

`=OR(C1="ACCOUNTING",ISNUMBER(FIND("Retl Wor",$C1))`,etc...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21341588)

Comment: This absolutely answers the question. However, my question mark was misleading and I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered as low quality, regardless they solve the problem or not.  Why don't you just edit your answer and elaborate on how this solves the issue ?